# intent.getAction() is returning NULL

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

In my app, I have added a splash screen and I have created the splash activity and made the appropriate changes to the manifest file. However, when I now run my app, the splash screen displays for its allotted time, and then returns a NullPointerException. The problem is being caused by

```
 intent.getAction()
```

On line 241 of the class my splash redirects to, intent.getAction() is returning null. It is my understanding that the action is grabbed from the manifest file for the specified activity. That is correct isnt it? If so, can someone look at this and see if I have buggered something up? I see nothing wrong.

```
 <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">       

    </activity>

   <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

__*_*__*_*__*_**If statement that is retrieving the action****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();

    System.out.println("Intent action is " + intent.getAction());
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)) {
        bimg[5].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mReturnIntent = true;
 } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET)) {
        Log.e("MAIN", "Widget action, string = " + intent.getExtras().getString("folder"));
        mHandler.updateDirectory(mFileMag.getNextDir(intent.getExtras().getString("folder"), true));

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to listen to?

Comment: Im retrieving the action of the intent for an if statement. See abpve. Ive added the If statement Im using.

Comment: This is not enough information to explain what you'retrying to do.. as your actions are not clear. Also we need to know what flow actions/setup you have to grab what you want.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The action is grabbed from the Intent that started the activity. The manifest intent-filters define what kinds of intents will be matched in addition to those that directly specify that activity as a target.

It's entirely normal for the action to be null if you started the activity with something like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MyTargetActivity.class));
```

You didn't specify an action for the Intent, so there isn't one. When testing the received intent's action, it's often useful to reverse the check like this:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    // ...
}
```

to avoid the need for an explicit null check, since the constant `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` isn't going to be null.

(Note that your code will still have to do something reasonable even if none of your action checks match in a case like this.)

Comment: But shouldn't the action be grabbed from the AndroidManifest.xml when the activity is launched? I am launching the activity just as you noted.

Comment: No, see the edit at the top of the answer. The intent-filters are just filters defining what kinds of more general intents can be matched. If you startActivity for an intent that directly targets that one activity by name, it doesn't have an action unless you specifically give it one. intent-filters are never used to "fill in" additional info in an intent, the intent will always contain only what the intent's creator added to it.

Comment: Man...I was way off then! Thanks for your help! By chance do you have an example handy of setting an intent action?

Comment: `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)`, `myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)`, etc. :) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: You're welcome! Now drop the splash screen, just launch into your app. It's cleaner. ;)

Comment: This make lots of sense, cause the string value can never be null