# getting action of buttons on receive() method which is a method of broadcast receiver but its show a null

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am getting action of buttons by `getaction` on `receive()` method which is a method of broadcast receiver but its sho a null plz tell me what I do in this to get a value which is not null
+my notify method is following

```
private void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage) 
    {
        String ns=Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(ns);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Notification notification=new Notification(R.drawable.bg,"Time",System.currentTimeMillis());
        RemoteViews notificationView=new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.main);
        Intent notificationIntent=new Intent(this,PlayerAudioActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.contentView=notificationView;
        notification.flags|=Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        //supposed button call intent
        Intent switchIntent=new Intent(this,MyReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, switchIntent, 0);
        notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPrevious, pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

-my broadcastreceiver class is following

```
public class MyReceiver 
extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "waaaawoooooooooOOOOOOjnjkhdfku";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         final String action=intent.getAction();
        // if(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)){
        Log.d(TAG, ""+action);
//           Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
//           String ieString=extras.getString("Locale");
    //       try{
//               final int Appwidgid=extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
//               if(Appwidgid!=AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID)
//               {
//                   this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { Appwidgid });
//               }
//            else {
//                onReceive(context, intent);
//                 }
//              context.startService(new Intent(context,PlayerAudioActivity.class));
//              Log.i(TAG,"Starting Service ConnectivityListener");
//          }catch(Exception e){
//              Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
//          }
//       }
    }

    private void onDeleted(Context context, int[] is) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

+manifest file is following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Audio.audioplayer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">

 <intent-filter>        
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/><action   
android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/><action  
android:name="android.net.conn.DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Audio.audioplayer.PlayerAudioActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PlayListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.Audio.audioplayer.PlayerAudioActivity" />

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(this, MyTargetActivity.class)); is this to write on onrecieve method

Comment: I am not understand plz tell me some more detail I am a new Android Developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As adamp mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048883/intent-getaction-is-returning-null) you cannot access an action on an intent that you've not set:

```
{...}
//supposed button call intent
Intent switchIntent=new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, switchIntent, 0);
{...}
```

You have to add your designated action to that intent by using [setAction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction%28java.lang.String%29).

Something like this:

```
{...}
Intent switchIntent=new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
switchIntent.setAction("YOUR_ACTION");
PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, switchIntent, 0);
{...}
```

ps: just pseudo code

Comment: great broo but i call onclicklistener on this comparing how i do like as public void onClick(View v) {
//    Log.d("clling play","yesss");
    if(mp.isPlaying())
    {
     if(mp!=null)
     {
      mp.pause();
      btnplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
     }
    }
    else
    {
     if(mp!=null)
     {
      mp.start();
      btnplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
     }
 
    }
   }
 but that are in main activity and tha value which is comparing in broadcastreciever what i do