# DELPHI 10.4, receive output result via Broadcast of Barcode Scanner

Tags: delphi, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a **Sunmi L2s** device, and I'm trying to receive the result of a barcode scan via a broadcast to an Android app. I would like to create an app that, when I push the hardware button for scan (orange button to the side of the phone), shows the barcode on a `TLabel.Text` in the app.

I've found code here on StackOverflow, but I can't make it receive the results, and I'm getting a message when the app starts that says "External exception 0".

I'm new to Delphi/Android development, so any help is welcome!

```pascal
implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses
  FMX.Platform.Android, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, Androidapi.JNI.Net,  
  Androidapi.JNI.Os, Androidapi.Helpers;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  AppEventService: IFMXApplicationEventService;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXApplicationEventService, AppEventService) then
    AppEventService.SetApplicationEventHandler(HandleAppEvent);
      
  MainActivity.registerIntentAction(StringToJString('com.sunmi.scanner.ACTION_DATA_CODE_RECEIVED'));
  TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageReceivedNotification, HandleActivityMessage);
end;

procedure TForm4.HandleActivityMessage(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
begin
  if M is TMessageReceivedNotification then
    HandleIntentAction(TMessageReceivedNotification(M).Value);
end;

function TForm4.HandleAppEvent(AAppEvent: TApplicationEvent; AContext: TObject): Boolean;
var
  StartupIntent: JIntent;
begin
  Result := False;
  if AAppEvent = TApplicationEvent.BecameActive then
  begin
    StartupIntent := MainActivity.getIntent;
    if StartupIntent <> nil then
      HandleIntentAction(StartupIntent);
  end;
end;

function TForm4.HandleIntentAction(const Data: JIntent): Boolean;
var
  JStr: JString;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (Data <> nil) and Data.getAction.equals(StringToJString('com.sunmi.scanner')) then
  begin
    JStr := Data.getStringExtra(StringToJString('Data'));
    Label1.Text := JStringToString(JStr);
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 3):

One issue I see that could be causing your "External exception" error is that in `HandleIntentAction()`, [`Data.getAction()` *can* potentially return `nil`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048883/), which you are not checking for.  Also, you need to compare the *complete* action name, not a prefix of it.

Change this:

```pascal
Data.getAction.equals(StringToJString('com.sunmi.scanner'))
```

To this instead:

```pascal
StringToJString('com.sunmi.scanner.ACTION_DATA_CODE_RECEIVED').equals(Data.getAction)
```

Other than that, the only other potential issue I see is in `HandleAppEvent()`, are you sure `BecameActive` is the best event to use to handle the `StartupIntent`? I would think `FinishedLaunching` would be a more appropriate event. An app can gain and lose focus multiple times during its lifetime, so you wouldn't want to handle the same startup `Intent` object over and over.  Otherwise, at the very least, after you have processed the `StartupIntent`, you could optionally call `MainActivity.setIntent(nil)` so that `MainActivity.getIntent()` won't return the same `Intent` object anymore on subsequent events.  Or, you could simply get rid of `HandleAppEvent()` and just handle the `StartupIntent` directly in your Form's `OnCreate` event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It fixes the "External exception" error message. But still doesnt get the scanning result,  maybe i do something wrong with the action name or something else.

Answer (score 0):

The post is a bit old, however maybe you are querying the wrong key 'Data' instead of 'data' which seems to be the right default key for sunmi device :

```
JStr := Data.getStringExtra(StringToJString('Data'));
```

Replace it by

```
JStr := Data.getStringExtra(StringToJString('data'));
```

Comment: Complete solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74238406/application-doesnt-receive-intent-broadcast