# Application doesn't receive intent broadcast

Tags: android, delphi

Delphi Android mobile application is build with Delphi Alexandria (Delphi 11.1).

I receive broadcast from Zebra barcode scanner device.

I try to receive broadcast from Sunmi device and Unitech device, and it does not work.

Both Sunmi and Unitech are configured to output barcode using broadcast.

Application Manifest file :

```xml
<!-- Zebra - OK -->
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="fr.XXX.YYY.ACTION" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />             
</intent-filter>            
<intent-filter>
    <!-- SUNMI - Ko -->
    <action android:name="com.sunmi.scanner.ACTION_DATA_CODE_RECEIVED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <!-- Unitech - Ko -->
    <action android:name="unitech.scanservice.data" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

In my code I register the intents :

```pascal
MainActivity.registerIntentAction(StringToJString(bcZebra));
MainActivity.registerIntentAction(StringToJString(bcSunmi));
MainActivity.registerIntentAction(StringToJString(bcUnitech));
```

Then I process broadcast this way :

```pascal
function TfData.HandleIntentAction(const Data: JIntent): Boolean;
var bc : string;
begin
  TOSLog.d('********* SCAN ******************');
  TOSLog.d(JStringToString(Data.getAction));

  Result := False;
  if Data <> nil then begin
    // Zebra, bcZebraData = com.symbol.datawedge.data_string - Ok 
    if StringToJString(bcZebra).equals(Data.getAction) then begin
      bc := JStringToString(Data.getStringExtra(StringToJString(bcZebraData)));
      result := true;
      bcScan(bc);
    end
    
    // Sunmi, bcSunmiData = 'data' - Ko 
    else if StringToJString(bcSunmi).equals(Data.getAction) then begin
      bc := JStringToString(Data.getStringExtra(StringToJString(bcSunmiData)));
      result := true;
      bcScan(bc);
    end
    
    // Unitech, bcUnitechData = 'text' - Ko
    else if StringToJString(bcUnitech).equals(Data.getAction) then begin
      bc := JStringToString(Data.getStringExtra(StringToJString(bcUnitechData)));
      result := true;
      bcScan(bc);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

When I scan a barcode with a Zebra device, I can see that in log console :

```
********* SCAN ******************
fr.XXX.YYY.ACTION
```

I don't see it with Sunmi and Unitech, so the function is not called.

However, when I scan with the Sunmi device, I get this in general log :

> Sending non-protected broadcast com.sunmi.scanner.ACTION_DATA_CODE_RECEIVED from system 1269:com.sunmi.scanner/u0a74 pkg com.sunmi.scanner

With Unitech :

> 10-28 18:44:30.199: E/ActivityManager(1178): Sending non-protected broadcast unitech.scanservice.data from system 2360:com.unitech.scanservice/1000 pkg com.unitech.scanservice

I can't figure out what I missed, and as Zebra do not log anything when it sends a broadcast, I'm unable to compare the 2 other devices.

Comment: Related/dupe (but unresolved) : [DELPHI 10.4, receive output result via Broadcast of Barcode Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70200780/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick glance of the docs for both Sunmi and Unitech suggests that you need to do it using a BroadcastReceiver that gets registered, with the appropriate actions. The following code is based around what is in the old [Kastri Free](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/blob/master/Core/DW.MultiReceiver.Android.pas) repo.

The first is a unit that defines a class that will handle any actions:

```
unit MultiReceiver;

interface

uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.Embarcadero;

type
  TMultiReceiver = class;

  TMultiReceiverListener = class(TJavaLocal, JFMXBroadcastReceiverListener)
  private
    FMultiReceiver: TMultiReceiver;
  public
    { JFMXBroadcastReceiverListener }
    procedure onReceive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent); cdecl;
  public
    constructor Create(const AMultiReceiver: TMultiReceiver);
  end;

  TIntentEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; const Intent: JIntent) of object;

  TMultiReceiver = class(TObject)
  private
    FBroadcastReceiver: JFMXBroadcastReceiver;
    FIntentFilter: JIntentFilter;
    FReceiverListener: TMultiReceiverListener;
    FOnIntent: TIntentEvent;
  protected
    procedure Receive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent); virtual;
    procedure ConfigureActions; virtual; abstract;
    property IntentFilter: JIntentFilter read FIntentFilter;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property OnIntent: TIntentEvent read FOnIntent write FOnIntent;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Androidapi.Helpers;

{ TMultiReceiverListener }

constructor TMultiReceiverListener.Create(const AMultiReceiver: TMultiReceiver);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FMultiReceiver := AMultiReceiver;
end;

procedure TMultiReceiverListener.onReceive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent);
begin
  FMultiReceiver.Receive(context, intent);
end;

{ TMultiReceiver }

constructor TMultiReceiver.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FReceiverListener := TMultiReceiverListener.Create(Self);
  FBroadcastReceiver := TJFMXBroadcastReceiver.JavaClass.init(FReceiverListener);
  FIntentFilter := TJIntentFilter.JavaClass.init;
  ConfigureActions;
  TAndroidHelper.Context.registerReceiver(FBroadcastReceiver, FIntentFilter)
end;

destructor TMultiReceiver.Destroy;
begin
  TAndroidHelper.Context.unregisterReceiver(FBroadcastReceiver)
end;

procedure TMultiReceiver.Receive(context: JContext; intent: JIntent);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnIntent) then
    FOnIntent(Self, intent);
end;

end.
```

Then an example of how you might use it:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  MultiReceiver;

type
  TScannerReceiver = class(TMultiReceiver)
  protected
    procedure ConfigureActions; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    FScannerReceiver: TScannerReceiver;
    procedure ScannerReceiverIntentHandler(Sender: TObject; const AIntent: JIntent);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses
  Androidapi.Helpers;

const
  cActionSunmi = 'com.sunmi.scanner.ACTION_DATA_CODE_RECEIVED';
  cActionUnitech = 'unitech.scanservice.data';

{ TScannerReceiver }

procedure TScannerReceiver.ConfigureActions;
begin
  IntentFilter.addAction(StringToJString(cActionSunmi));
  IntentFilter.addAction(StringToJString(cActionUnitech));
end;

{ TForm1 }

constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FScannerReceiver := TScannerReceiver.Create;
  FScannerReceiver.OnIntent := ScannerReceiverIntentHandler;
end;

procedure TForm1.ScannerReceiverIntentHandler(Sender: TObject; const AIntent: JIntent);
begin
  if AIntent.getAction.Equals(StringToJString(cActionSunmi)) then
  begin
    // Handle Sunmi
  end
  else if AIntent.getAction.Equals(StringToJString(cActionUnitech)) then
  begin
    // Handle Unitech
  end;
end;

end.
```

**NOTE: This is completely untested as I do not have either of the models handled by it**

Comment: Modern Delphi versions have built-in support for receiving broadcasts without creating a custom broadcast receiver. You can receive broadcasts using `MainActivity.registerIntentAction()` and then `TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageReceivedNotification)`. Which, I believe, the OP is already doing.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, I think that's what I'm doing in my code. I also tried using a class TMultiReceiver that I already use to get messages from a background service and I get no more success, nothing is received.

Comment: I made a mistake when I tried using broadcastReceiver because the receiver I created listened only local broadcasts (background service). It works when listening to other app. Finally, what is the exact differences between the two ways Receiver/MainActivity.registerIntentAction() ?

Comment: registerIntentAction is for when an app is sent an intent using startActivity, not for receiving broadcasts. This is the [relevant documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/FMX.Android_Intents_Sample)